# "Invalid or unexpected token" while deploying to firebase functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I was trying to deploy my react ssr to firebase functions and this error appeared to me, can someone help me?

```
i  functions: Watching "C:\Users\LucasPereira\Documents\Dev\Site\ProIT\frontend\functions" for Cloud Functions...
!  C:\Users\LucasPereira\Documents\Dev\Site\ProIT\frontend\functions\src\assets\gif_pro_it.gif:1
GIF89a


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1215:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LucasPereira\Documents\Dev\Site\ProIT\frontend\functions\src\pages\Home\index.js:22:42)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
!  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
```

This is my index.tx(root)

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import App from './src/App';

import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';

const index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf-8');

const app = express();
app.get('**', (req, res)=>{
    const html = renderToString(<App />);
    const finalHtml = index.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${html}</div>`);
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
    res.send(finalHtml);
})

export let ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is my firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrapp",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": {},
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

NOTE: I'm using express 4.17.1, and node version 14.
The host is working very well i'm only having problem with functions

EDIT: I change the ".gif" and it continues showing error, so I decided to remove it, only for debug, well, the error continues to another image(another PNG), the error appears to be in images

Comment: Hello, can you share your Cloud Function code.

Comment: On Stack Ovetflow, questions should contain enough information so that anyone can reproduce the error on their own.  Just showing an error message is insufficient.  Please edit the question to explain fully what you're working with.  It might help to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post updated, sorry about that!

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? I see gif_pro_it.gif:1GIF89a. Is the colon (:) part of the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to import a *.gif image somewhere (but not in the provided code); by default, importing GIFs is not supported.

If I'm correct, then you need to setup [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) (or its alternatives) in order to handle imports of GIF files.